# Hibernate - OneToMany, each reference to different table without cross - reference table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have next problem:

```
package com.hibernate.example.question;
public class Attribute{
   private String valule;
   private String description;
   //getters and setters
}

package com.hibernate.example.question;
public class AttributeOwner{
   Set<Attribute>  attributes;
   //getter and setter
}

package com.hibernate.example.question;
public class A extends AttributeOwner
{
   //some A fields and methods
}

package com.hibernate.example.question;
public class B extends AttributeOwner
{
   //some B fields and methods
}

package com.hibernate.example.question;
public class C extends AttributeOwner
{
   //some C fields and methods
}
```

Each of this classes is in its own file. I would like to save Attribute in 3 different tables: AAttributes, BAttributes and CAttributes - 2 columns in that table would be same: value and description, but each Attribute type (A,B or C) would have it's own ID (Attribute_ID), and A_ID/B_ID/C_ID - reference to row of table A/B/C.
I don't want to have Attribute in one table, and 3 cross - reference tables with 2 columns, linking to one row of Attribute table and one row of it's owner (row of A/B or C table).
Is it possible to implement such thing using Hibernate?

Comment: If an Attribute entity can only belong to one owner, there is no reason not to create three nullable collumns like: OWNER_A, OWNER_B, OWNER_C. Only one of them needs to be populated, which can be validated programmatically.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a waste of memory? Each time when I create an subclass A_n, I would have to add another nullable column to that table. Imagine that Attribute table has 10^6 row's. I will loose (n-1)*10^6 * 8 B (ID of OWNER is Long value) in start - if i have n subclasses of AttributeOwner.

Comment: In order to decide which approach is most efficient, you need to *know* how many subclasses you're going to have. At least to the extent of knowing whether you're likely to be adding new implementations frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont make that three classes that extends from AttributeOwner share the id of the father. Make it them unique with the combination AttributeOwner_ID-A_ID,AttributeOwner_ID-B_ID,AttributeOwner_ID-C_ID, You just have to give the AttributeOwner and  Id attribute and use
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)